# Angular 6 and Spring4 MVC with same server

Tags: spring-mvc, angular6

[image]

how to integrate between angular 6 and Spring 4 MVC which Angular will be client and Spring 4 MVC will be server and they will communicate via restapi, I need the consulting.

Comment: which error do you obtains? which is your problem?